# Do I earn Mastery rank while waiting for test

Tags: warframe

I failed my mastery rank test and have to wait 24 hours. Do I still accumulate XP/affinity toward the next rank while I wait or does it fizzle until I pass the test?
Want to know if I should avoid leveling till after I pass the test.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Excess mastery points are not lost if a player reaches the amount
>   required to advance a rank — these will automatically fill the next
>   mastery bar, displayed only once the player has succeeded on the
>   rank-up test.

http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Mastery_Rank